# Converting a multi-page PDF into single-page PDFs and extracting image

Tags: php, linux

I have a multi-page PDF file that has information I need to parse. The information and picture is confined to its own page. I need to extract the text and image from the PDF.

I'm using CentOS and PHP.

My attempt:

I originally tried using a combination of pdftotext and imagemagick. I converted the PDF into an image and that actually separated the pages into their own images. Unfortunately the quality of the image on the page came out very poor.

My goal:

I need to split the PDF into multiple PDFs, one per page. Then, I need to extract the image from that page with the best quality possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you install new software, like `pdftk`?

Comment: I have root access, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagemagick does not fit to perform this task

when you need to extract images from a pdf, at their **original** size (i.e. the best, since any other resolution is or lesser or bigger than original), you must to use

**pdfimages**

http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

(*static* binaries are available if you cannot compile from source)

syntax:

```
pdfimages file.pdf image-root
```

the image resulting will have the extension **.ppm** , unless you add the switch **-j** to have jpeg images as output

Answer (score -1):

## pdfseparate to split multi-page.pdf to 1.pdf 2.pdf … + convert 1.pdf 1.png …

### [pdfseparate](https://manpages.org/pdfseparate) (part of [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org)) to split multi-page.pdf to 1.pdf 2.pdf …

```
pdfseparate multi-page.pdf ./single-pages/%d.pdf
```

- extracts all pages from multi-page.pdf
- and saves them as single page PDFs, (`%d` variable for page number)

### [mogrify](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) (part of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/)) to batch convert all single page PDFs to PNGs at your desired resolution (in DPI)

```
mogrify ./single-pages/*.pdf -density 300 -format png
```